# Get Filtered records into Array Variant without looping VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10 records in excel of which i have edited 3rd and 7th records and placing a flag/string "modified" in certain column belongs to same rows to filter while processing

Below is the code that i am working with which is fetching only the first record(3rd) and not the 7th record into array using VBA

```
 Dim RecordsArray() As Variant
   Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RMData")
   sht.Range("M1:M100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Modified"
   sht.Range("A2:A100").Rows.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
   col = [a2].CurrentRegion.Columns.count
   lw = [a2].End(xlDown).Row

   RecordsArray = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lw,col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Idea is I want to get those two records without looping and searching for 
"Modified" string for the edited row

Comment: what's the problem with loops?

Comment: Basically, to uphold the performance, if i have 3000 filtered rows then it takes time to loop those 3000 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid dealing with the visible areas mentioned already, you can try something like this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyVisibleToArray()
    Dim recordsArray As Variant, ws As Worksheet, nextAvailable As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RMData")
    Set nextAvailable = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    With ws.Range("M1:M100")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Modified"
        If .Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then

            'copy - paste visibles in col A, under all data
            ws.UsedRange.Columns("A:M").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nextAvailable

            Set nextAvailable = nextAvailable.Offset(1)
            nextAvailable.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Delete       'Delete the (visible) header
            recordsArray = nextAvailable.CurrentRegion      'Get the cells as array
            nextAvailable.CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Delete    'Delete the temporary range
        End If
        .AutoFilter
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

---

To copy just column A to array use this: `ws.UsedRange.Columns("A")`

[image: v1]

To copy columns A to M use this: `ws.UsedRange.Columns("A:M")`

[image: v2]

Comment: Paul, Attached my sheet which i am using for this example

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for your reponse on this . When i ran your code , I got only the first column "A" values copied into the array . my record set contains values till K coulmn. Is there something we are missing in the above code . Attached my Excel sheet above, you can see first column copied and not other columns at the below of the last row

Comment: Thanks Paul, with small correction by giving my range I could able to read the edited rows into array   ws.Range("A2:K20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nextAvailable

Comment: My opinion as there are no loops in your code thinking it will be faster reading the edited rows copying into a range in the same sheet and fetching the records....great thing...Thanks PAUL once again

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I made a change to copy columns A to M as well, and show you what to change

Comment: Thanks paul,  Application.ScreenUpdating = False helped me in resolving one issue which i am facing . actually i am able to see the filtered rows in the middle somewhere in the sheet . when i kept that above line it is no more appearing and working perfectly!!

Comment: Hi Paul, Can you help me on this as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899228/dynamics-365-working-with-excel

Answer (score 2):

When reading a Filtered Range, most likely there will be splits ranges, the rows will not be continuous, so you need to loop through the `Areas` of the Filtered Range.

Also, you might have a few `Rows` in each `Area`, so you should loop through the `Area.Rows`.

More detailed comments in my code below.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Populated2DArrayfromFilterRange()

Dim RecordsArray() As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim col As Long, lw As Long, i As Long

Dim FiltRng As Range, myArea As Range, myRow As Range

ReDim RecordsArray(0 To 1000) ' redim size of array to high number >> will optimize later

' set the worksheet object
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RMData")

i = 0 ' reset array element index

' use With statement to fully qualify all Range and Cells objects nested inside
With sht
    .Range("M1:M100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Modified"
    .Range("A2:A100").Rows.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)

    col = .Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    lw = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    ' set the filtered range
    Set FiltRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lw, col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'    Debug.Print FiltRng.Address(0, 0)

    For Each myArea In FiltRng.Areas ' <-- loop through areas
        For Each myRow In myArea.Rows ' <-- loop through rows in area
            RecordsArray(i) = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myRow))
            i = i + 1 ' raise array index by 1
        Next myRow
    Next myArea

    ReDim Preserve RecordsArray(0 To i - 1) ' optimize array size to actual populated size
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a hidden row in the middle, then `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will return multiple [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/areas-object-excel).  Assigning a range to an Array **only assigns the first Area**.  (At also *always* makes the array 2D)

Instead of looping & searching for "Modified", you *could* just loop `For Each` cell in the `SpecialCells` range and assign that to the array instead - if you plan was "no loops at all" then this is not what you want.  (But, I would then have to ask you "why not?"!)

```vb
Dim RecordsArray() As Variant, rFiltered As Range, rCell As Range, lCount As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RMData")
sht.Range("M1:M100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Modified"
sht.Range("A2:A100").Rows.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
col = [a2].CurrentRegion.Columns.Count 'This will act on ActiveSheet, not sht - is that intended?
lw = [a2].End(xlDown).Row 'In case of gaps, would "lw=sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row" be better?

'RecordsArray = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lw, col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rFiltered = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lw, col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
ReDim RecordsArray(1 To rFiltered.Cells.Count, 1) 'Mimic default assignment
lCount = 1
For Each rCell In rFiltered
    RecordsArray(lCount, 1) = rCell.Value
    lCount = lCount + 1
Next rTMP
Set rCell = Nothing
Set rFiltered = Nothing
```